# change with CSS the color of an svg background image set with "background-image: url()"

Tags: images, css, custom-background, svg

does anyone knows if it is possible to change the color (the stroke and fill attributes) of a SVG illustration used as a background with background-image: url() directly via CSS?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can absolutely do this with SVG, as long as you're using inline SVG code, which you'll need a program like Adobe Illustrator to produce. You may be able to use an online tool (like [this one](https://editor.method.ac/)) but I haven't tried that.

Chris Coyier of CSSTricks.com [did an excellent write up of this](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#using-inline-svg).

Fork [his SVG codepen](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/evcBu) and play around with it to get a feel for how it works.

Good luck!

Comment: Question is asking for control color of a SVG used as background image. This answer refers to a SVG image (not as background)